# why MapWindowPoints set all boundaries to zero

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm calling the MapWindowPoints API function and it fails if I call it after creating the window, It set all members of CRect r are set to zero.

```
CRect r;
GetWindowRect(&r);
HWND desktop = GetDesktopWindow();
HWND parent = GetParent()->GetSafeHwnd();
int result = ::MapWindowPoints(desktop, parent, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&r), 2);
```

after the call of MapWindowPoints the result is not zero so it didn't fail, the number is large negative number, As this page mentioned it fails if return is zero http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145046(v=vs.85).aspx , after calling GetWindowRect and before calling MapWindowPoints the r contains the real boundaries of window.

Comment: Could you describe what are the involved windows? And what kind of thing you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Instead of using the result of `GetDesktopWindow()` try passing `NULL` or `HWND_DESKTOP` as the first parameter for `MapWindowPoints`.

Comment: @manuell: the window is custom grid control it is old code written in OWL I moved it to the MFC , I faced this problem when I call create method the control is created and has a valid handle and GetWindowRect return a valid boundaries, The programmer was trying to adjust the position of the custom control according to it's parent, What is strange is the behaviour of MapWindowPoints, all boundaries become zero so the calculated width of the control will be false and it is zero the custom control is hidden

Comment: @JonathanPotter: It was like what you recommended, but I added those temporary vars to be sure if they has values.

Comment: Please Edit the "is zero {0, 0, 0, 0}, after calling GetWindowRect" part.

Comment: @manuell: I hope it is now fine

Comment: Really weird. Can't think of a way to obtain such result. By curiosity, could you give the "r" values before, and the int result value ?

Comment: The reinterpret_cast is not necessary if you make `r` a pointer to `POINT` -- try it and see if you get the same result. I might be mistaken on this, but the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145046(v=vs.85).aspx) says "This parameter can also point to a RECT structure", while you make it point to a `CRect`. Are those *really* the same? `CRect` is a class, while `Rect` is a simple structure.

Comment: "Large negative number" always means something.  If it is -858993460 then your code snippet doesn't match your real code.  Convert it to hex.

Comment: What do you expect to happen, if you have the window coordinates. AFAIK maaping this coordinates to the Desktop coordinates should Change nothing. Please explain why do you want to do this?

Comment: @manuell: r = {top=244 bottom=244 left=63 right=63}, result = -15925311, after calling MapWindowPoints r = {top=0 bottom=0 left=0 right=0}

Comment: @Jongware: this didn't affect it.

Comment: @HansPassant: look at my comment to manuell it contains the values.

Comment: @xMRi: the window coordinates are the screen coordinates that are the same as desktop window, and we want to map it to the parent dialog of the custom control, this can be obtained in many different ways I solved it for this dialog but I'm asking in general, many other parts of the code use this way I want all of it to stay working as it was previously before migrating from OWL to MFC, we have millions of lines of code it can't be traced.

Comment: You just got (-244, -63) as a return value.  That certainly matches the argument values.

Comment: Seems legit, if the parent is at -244, -63. As your control is zero sized, you get {0,0,0,0} Show the Parent Rect, please.

Comment: But if you have screen coordinates why, don't you use ScreenToClient?

Comment: after I noticed that width, height are zero I fout that user called create for a control that is in the resource dialog, I just needed to call ::DDX_Control when calling the create it created a new dynamic control and in the dynamic creation I depend attributes stored on the base class this attribute contains the x, y, width, height,style, styleEx,... it is all zero by default, that is what caused the misunderstanding and the behaviour of the method was right. I fixed it by getting the parent and calling GetDlgItem(myId) if it retun handle then it is on the resources and call DDX_Control.